# insert image from https://storage.cloud.google.com with format

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a problem with inserting images in a google document with app scripts.

All my images are stored in https://storage.cloud.google.com with format https://storage.cloud.google.com//100x120/86d932ad-b649-4c38-adaf-ae0071ea3ecd

and my code is like this:

/**
     * Insert new paragraph with parameter 
     */
    function createDocument(iData) {

```
   var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
   var body = doc.getBody();

  // Access the body of the document, then add a paragraph.
  // Retrieve an image from the web.
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(iData[5])
  Logger.log(resp.getContentText());
  var celdas = [
     [iData[5], 'User: ' + iData[0]],
     [, 'Name: ' + iData[1]],
     [, 'U.O.  : ' + iData[2]],
     [, 'Email : ' + iData[3]],
     [, 'Phone : ' + iData[4]]
 ];

 doc.getBody().appendTable(celdas);
 doc.getBody().appendImage(resp.getBlob());
```

}

The info is stored in Array iData, and it´s not working.
the table is successfully created but the image does not appear

Answer (score 0):

(a) You have two slashes in your image path after domain:

https://storage.cloud.google.com//100x120/86d932ad-b649-4c38-adaf-ae0071ea3ecd

There should be only one.

(b) Make sure that these images are publicly accessible. Check "Share publicly" setting in your Cloud console.

(c) Make sure that these files have correct MIME type set, e.g. "image/jpeg" - or whatever their type is. Since the file URI does not end with ".jpg", the browser may not interpret them correctly.